# What is the best way to have date and time input in html (from user) and receive in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I want to get user input in form of date and time (html), turn them into proper Date objects (javascript) and store using Firebase backend. This is to take user input for a future event and do something when that exact time comes. But haven't found a convincing way to have a form or something in html.

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="e">
```

In above, datetime-local is not only cumbersome but its AM/PM doesn't seem nice. 
Thanks.

Comment: The best way to enter date and time is to use one of the many date/time widgets that exist out there in the world. Which you choose will depend on a lot of factors. Are you using straight JavaScript? jQuery? Angular? React?

Comment: try using `moment` : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
I am just using Javascript straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would flatpickr work for you?

Demos at https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/

Your code might look like:

```js
var options = {
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        alert("dates: " + selectedDates + " - dateStr: " + dateStr + " instance: " + instance);
    },
};
flatpickr(document.querySelector("#widget"), options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<div id="widget">Click this to edit time</div>
```

Read about more events at https://flatpickr.js.org/events/

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks great! My knowledge of jQuery is very little, so now I will just need to figure out how to get the value the user selects so that I can store in firebase. 
Also I would love to show the selected value in a textbox as it is shown in the examples in the website.

Comment: I've added to the original snippet an event handler. If you find you need more help with other aspects - please consider opening a separate question

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Just one last query: how exactly I ensure I don't have to get access to flatpickr online. I mean if I could 'download' and store locally so that it will always work irrespective of if their server is down then it would be great. Sorry for such basic doubt, but I am a beginner in jquery related stuff. 
If this is a doubt worth having another question then I am happy to do so.

Comment: Those urls have a `download` button. This is where it's currently pointing: https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/archive/master.zip